# Use Ajax forms for my requests or consume a RESTful service from a browser that only supports GET and POST methods in mvc4 web api

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am working on mvc4 web api application I am using

```
@{
        AjaxOptions addAjaxOpts = new AjaxOptions {
            OnSuccess = "getData",
            Url = "/api/reservation"
        };
    }
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm(addAjaxOpts)) { 
        @Html.Hidden("ReservationId", 0) 
        <p><label>Name:</label>@Html.Editor("ClientName")</p>
        <p><label>Location:</label>@Html.Editor("Location")</p>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    }
```

for adding and it submits the form to PostReservation method in the ApiController
but when I am trying to use Ajax.BeginForm in editing it submits the request to the PostReservation not to PutReservation.
I also tried to put @Html.HttpMethodOverride(HTTPVerbs.Put) inside the form but still not working

Answer (score 0):

An HTML form only supports POST or GET. You can manually do an ajax call in the browser specifying the HTTP Method or you can use Http tunelling as you are doing, but this last one that requires custom code on ASP.NET Web API to do the routing. ASP.NET Web API does not do HTTP Tunelling out of the box.

You need a HttpMessageHandler like this to support tunelling,

```
public class MethodTunellingDelegatingHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (request.Method == HttpMethod.Post && request.Headers.Contains("X-HTTP-Method-Override"))
        {
            var newMethod = request.Headers.GetValues("X-HTTP-Method-Override").FirstOrDefault();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(newMethod)) {
                request.Method = new HttpMethod(newMethod);
            }
        }
        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am sorry but I do not understand how to use your class ?

Comment: You need to inject that handler in the Web API configuration as it is shown here, http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/http-message-handlers